# When does data obtained via d3 queue().defer() appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Consider the following snippet - which attempts to track the progress of data operations occurring through `d3.queue().defer()` :

```
var data = [];
function analyze(error, f ) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Inside analyze: f.length=' + f.length);
    data.push(f);
}
var q = d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, fnames[0])
    .await(analyze);

console.log('after queue: data.len=' + data.length);

function updateViz(data2) {
   // Do some d3 stuff with data2.. takes some time..
   // .. 
    console.log('Finished updateViz: data2.len=' + data2.length);
}

updateViz(data);
console.log('after updateViz: len=' + data.length);
```

The output - as vieweed in the `chrome` javascript console is:

[image]

So then: the data is appearing only after a moderately lengthy operation (`udpateViz()`).

The issue is:  I need the data available at the *beginning* of that method. Also more generally: what can be done to have a deterministic completion of the `queue().defer()` - so that subsequent operations may be able to depend on the data being present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3.queue is an asynchronous function meaning that execution of further code (as calling of updateViz) does not wait for it to complete. The easiest solution is to put the code that depends on completion of d3.queue into its callback function. The callback function of d3.queue is always executed after all the deferred steps are completed.

```
var q = d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, fnames[0])
    .await(updateViz);

function updateViz(error, data2) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    updateViz(data2);
}
```

Comment: OK! that makes sense. Trying it out now: I have two methods that need to be chained. Hoping to put the first into defer(chained1).await(chained2)

Comment: I was *not* able to get the chained functions to work ;(

Comment: thx. It works for multiple files but not for multiple independent functions.  Well I just simplified my logic and am using just one function. I'm just *not* a javascript person. Multithreading and declarative programming are more my things.